# HTMLPurifier without XML declaration

Tags: php, xml, htmlpurifier

I am using **HTMLPurifier** on PHP to clean some dirty HTML, as follows:

```
$H=new HTMLPurifier()
$content_text_fixHTML = $H->purify($content_text);
```

**Note**: Omited encoding set up, because it is UTF-8

But, it will output the XML encoding declaration at the top.

```
<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

I do not want it. How do I prevent HTMLPurifier from adding it?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need cut result string

```
$n = strlen('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>');
$content_text_fixHTML = substr($H->purify($content_text), $n);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this the cleanest way of doing it? Can't I set up HTMLPurifier to not include it, instead of removing it afterwards? Thanks friend.